# Spinner not available after change Activity to AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-menu, appcompatactivity

I changed the inheritance of myClass **from activity to appCompatActivity**. Originally there was a menu with a spinner as shown next:

myClass.java

```
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.messages, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menuTxtSize);
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) item.getActionView();
    int index = 1;
    spinner.setSelection(index);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    OTHER CODE
```

My messages.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:title="@string/string_txt_size"
        android:id="@+id/menuTxtSize"
        android:showAsAction="always" 
        android:actionLayout="@layout/view_spinner"  />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_refresh"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/action_refresh"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_refresh_24dp" />
</menu>
```

My spinner.xml

```
<Spinner xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:entries="@array/txt_size_values"
    />
```

And array for spinner

```
<string-array name="txt_size_values">
    <item>Мелко</item>
    <item>Средне</item>
    <item>Крупно</item>
</string-array>
```

And all looked fine

[image]

***To go to appkompat I changed:***

**1.** In myClass

`Spinner spinner = (Spinner) item.getActionView();`

to `AppCompatSpinner spinner = (AppCompatSpinner) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);`

**2.** In  messeges.xml add **app:**-namespace and add **app:actionViewClass**

```
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:title="@string/string_txt_size"
        android:id="@+id/menuTxtSize"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/view_spinner"  />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_refresh"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/action_refresh"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_refresh_24dp" />
</menu>
```

**3.** Also i changed **application theme** to `android:theme="Theme.AppCompat"`

As a result I got the following

[image]

**Text disappeared.And spinner became unavailable for clicks**

How to fix this problem? Thanks

Comment: change app:showAsAction="ifRoom" to  app:showAsAction="Always" for spinner item

Comment: You should load spinner value via onResume() or onNewIntent() method again.

Comment: How can i load it if in onResume() no Menu parametr, like in onNewIntent()?

Comment: Use toolbar on the place of actionbar

Comment: remove actionLayout

Comment: actionLayout and actionView may give conflict.

Comment: @Ajith Pandian. How can i get drop-down list when i remove  `android:actionLayout="@layout/view_spinner" `

Comment: You can set adapter to Spinner after inflating the menu layout.

Comment: AppCompatSpinner spinner = (AppCompatSpinner) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);  after this you can set your adapter like "spinner.setAdapter(yourAdapter);"